# Supertranslations & Superrotations and black holes

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes

I am currently (attempting to) the black hole memory effect and I am really struggling to find introductory explanations which simply state “this is what is meant by a supertranslation on a black hole horizon”.

I understand that they are asymptotic symmetries that contain the Poincare group and the “standard picture” of how a supertranslation leaves (for example) emitted beams unchanged at null infinity.

I am also able to derive the standard generator of supertranslations for the BMS group when we are talking about a metric of a blackhole given in Eddington-Finkelstein.

I suppose the problem I am having is understanding the correspondence between “leaving things unchanged at null infinity” and diffeomorphisms of the metric generated by supertranslations. Furthermore, I am having issues with understanding what a superrotation is and superrotation charge beyond the Maths found in Andrew Strominger’s notes. Any help in gaining physical intuition would be appreciated.